# Mapping unpredictable keys from JSON to POJO

Tags: json, jackson

I am using the Jackson JSON library to map JSON streams into POJO's.

My JSON's keys have unpredictable names.
i.e

```
{
  "Random_ID": 
   {
        "Another_Random_ID":  
        {
            "some_key": "value"
            "some_key1": "value1"
        }
   }
   ...  
}
```

I would like to map this request to a POJO (with the same structure), however the mapper will fail since there is no such setXXX (where XXX is a random_id - since i cannot predict the name).

What would be the best way to map this request to the corresponding object without manually parsing it with createJsonParser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If names are unpredictable, POJOs are not the way to go.

But you can use the Tree Model, like:

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(jsonSource);
```

and access it as a logical tree. Also, if you do want to convert the tree (or any of sub-trees, as identified by node that is the root of sub-tree), you can do:

```
MyPOJO pojo = objectMapper.treeToValue(node, MyPOJO.class);
```

and back to tree

```
JsonNode node = objectMapper.valueToTree(pojo);
```